# Eclipse 3.4 JSP validation question

Tags: eclipse-3.4

Why is eclipse saying `'No end Tag (</c:if>).'` on line 1 and `'No start tag (<c:if>)'` on line 4  of the following code snippet:

```
<c:if test="${ShowLoginLink}">
    Log in again and export the document as PDF.</p>
    <a href="${LoginLink}"><img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/linkIcon.jpg" width="17" height="17" style="float:left; padding-right: 3px; border: none;"/>Log In</a>
</c:if>
```

It works fine at runtime on the server.  I am just annoyed with eclipse validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a missing start paragraph  see line 2

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to get bugged by this validation you can simple disable all validations by right clicking on your project> validations> disable all validations.